# Play Video When Notification fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uilocalnotification

I am making an app in which user select time and video. When notification fire than I want that the select video should be played . How can i achieve that?
Here is my notification code.

```
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate
{

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Time to wake Up";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    localNotif.soundName = @"Tick-tock-sound.mp3";
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
    NSLog(@" date %lu",kCFCalendarUnitDay);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif]; 
}
```

Any Syggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for scheduling a local notification looks good. Probably you should also add some data in the `userInfo` property of the local notification, so that when it fires, you can check that property and do something different (play a specific video) according to the data inside the `userInfo`.

Example:

```
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"video1" forKey:@"videoName"];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
```

Make sure that you also request user permission for using local notifications, otherwise the local notification will not fire.

Example:

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

Now you need to handle the firing of the local notification when your app is in the 3 states: foreground, background/suspended and not running.

The app is running in the **foreground**. The local notification fires at the date you set it to. The following delegate method will get called by the system in `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    NSString *videoName = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"videoName"];
    //do something, probably play your specific video
}
```

The app is running in the **background or is suspended**. The local notification is shown to the user (it fired at the date you set it to) **and the user taps on it**. The same delegate method as above (`didReceiveLocalNotification`) will get called by the system in `AppDelegate`:

The app **is not running**, the local notification is shown to the user (it fired at the date you set it to) **and the user taps on it**. The following delegate method will get called by the system in `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif)
    {
       //the app was launched by tapping on a local notification
       NSString *videoName = [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"videoName"];
       // play your specific video
    } else {
       // the app wasn't launched by tapping on a local notification
       // do your regular stuff here
    }
}
```

I would recommend reading [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW32) regarding working with local notifications.

You can use the Media Player framework as recommended in *Glorfindel's answer* and you can find an example for playing a video in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578965/ios-play-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller).

Answer (score 0):

Once the user opens your local notification, your app will be launched, and the [`- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) of your `UIApplicationDelegate` will be called. The options dictionary will contain a [`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys) key, which contains the `UILocalNotification`. That should give you enough information to determine which video needs to be played, which you can do with the [Media Player framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006952).